# Do Snow Golems die in the rain?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know they have a weakness to water and will lose hearts but can they die if they enter the rain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they die in less then two seconds from rain.
Here is a wiki page that will tell you everthing you need to know about snow golems: [Snow Golem](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snow_Golem)